# hapijs v18 send response before handler completion

Tags: controller, hapi.js

I want to send a response from my hapijs handler before the handler completes.
I have tried `h.response().code(204).takeover()` however the response doesn't appear to be sent until it is explicitly returned from the handler and the documentation suggests the same.
I want to immediately return a 204 and then continue running code in the handler. Is there a way to continue processing after a response is sent?
The documentation for request.generateResponse() suggests that the reply interface can be used but I think this is just a documentation error as the reply interface links back to the response toolkit documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to continue to run async code after the response is sent if the async code execution is called before the response is returned.

```
async function someAsyncCode() {
  // Do processing
}

(request, h) => {
   someAsyncCode()
   return h.response('hello worl').code(204).takeover()   
}
```

Since you are not awaiting or returning the promise, the execution of the function "someAsyncCode" will not be blocking the execution flow.